# OAuth2 library from Manfred Steyer - Which events are covered in OAuthErrorEvents?

Tags: events, oauth-2.0

I saw this in the source code:

```
export type EventType =
  | 'discovery_document_loaded'
  | 'jwks_load_error'
  | 'invalid_nonce_in_state'
  | 'discovery_document_load_error'
  | 'discovery_document_validation_error'
  | 'user_profile_loaded'
  | 'user_profile_load_error'
  | 'token_received'
  | 'token_error'
  | 'code_error'
  | 'token_refreshed'
  | 'token_refresh_error'
  | 'silent_refresh_error'
  | 'silently_refreshed'
  | 'silent_refresh_timeout'
  | 'token_validation_error'
  | 'token_expires'
  | 'session_changed'
  | 'session_error'
  | 'session_terminated'
  | 'session_unchanged'
  | 'logout'
  | 'popup_closed'
  | 'popup_blocked'
  | 'token_revoke_error';

export abstract class OAuthEvent {
  constructor(readonly type: EventType) {}
}

export class OAuthSuccessEvent extends OAuthEvent {
  constructor(type: EventType, readonly info: any = null) {
    super(type);
  }
}

export class OAuthInfoEvent extends OAuthEvent {
  constructor(type: EventType, readonly info: any = null) {
    super(type);
  }
}

export class OAuthErrorEvent extends OAuthEvent {
  constructor(
    type: EventType,
    readonly reason: object,
    readonly params: object = null
  ) {
    super(type);
  }
}
```

How can I know which events are covered in OAuthErrorEvent? I am subscribing on the events and want to emit something if I receive an error-event, but I'm not sure which events are covered from the total.